# Do Java portlets block each other from rendering?

Tags: java, portlet

Pretty much what the title says. Are Java portlets able to render asynchronously as soon as they're ready, or does the page need to wait for every portlet to load first before the first render can occur? I've looked through the specification but haven't found anything concrete so far.

Comment: You can render all the portlets when you open the page. It does not mean you need to load/render the content. Once you have all of them on the page you can request each portlet's content with Ajax request (it's gonna be async). In another words - you can place the JavaScript in a portlet so that the portlet can asynchronously fetch content from its associated Web application.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you can render the bare minimum of the portlets first, which shouldnt take much time, and then asynchronously load the content of each one and they render as soon as they're ready? Is that method a standard part of the specification?
Thanks for the quick answer by the way.

Comment: I guess if you render the bare minimum - it's gonna be fast ) and when it comes to fetching real content - it can take time, but it's gonna be async actions (for some portlet it can be really fast while for another one it can take longer). I can't say this method is the part of the spec, I haven't been working with portlets for a long time, but I think this approach will work. You could try google other approaches or maybe somebody will provide something better :)

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/Director/books/pgPortletsAsync.html) will be helpful. I believe you can config your portal to do some stuff for you, and maybe if you mix it with the idea of fetching content using ajax - you will get what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I read the spec (JSR-286, as you don't mention a specific version), there's nothing that demands either serial or parallel rendering. It just specifies *that* portlets render. You just can't assume that you're still in the same HttpServletRequest handler as every other portlet.

Not only is it not specified, but even within one implementation it could differ. I've tested it with older versions of Liferay, where you had both options for a portlet: The platform transparently replaces the portlet's content with a dynamic placeholder, issuing an Ajax request to pull the rendered portlet's output. The simulated portlets in question just contained `Thread.sleep(2000)` in their render method.

While the specification of asynchronous rendering is not in JSR-286, in Liferay it's a single configuration value with no effect on the implementation, thus as platform independent as a vendor-specific add-on can be. If you go for any of the newer implementations, e.g. rendering rather static code that dynamically pulls its content anyways (through resource requests or from web services): This is fully working on top of the portlet spec, thus easily possible. Resource requests are standardised, web services are portal independent.

As of the newest Portlet-3.0 spec JSR-362: There are specific additions for JS-based rendering and a standardized JS side as well. I can't tell you much about it (yet), but as you didn't mention that standard explicitly, you might not have it in mind (yet).